# Jquery .each var name+index

Tags: jquery, indexing, each, var

I got this

```
    $('.thumbnail').each(function(index){
    var example = new.example();
    }
```

I want to make a different example for every thumbnail.
Something like, var example+index 
var example0, var example1, etc...

How do I do this? I can't find it!

Answer (score 0):

Try [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function(index){
    eval('var example'+ index +' = new.example()');
}
```

Comment: I tried it in a few ways but It still wont work! `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place,
    map: map,
     title:"Hello World!"
  });` this is my code that I'm trying to get the marker+index on. (place and map are variables.